# What is a good way to compile nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

I am new to NodeJS development using NodeJS10.x version. I read questions and it turns out Javascript cannot be compiled, but I wanted to know if there is a way I can identify code issues before deploying it to production environment. I am developing a serverless application using serverless framework and deploying it on AWS. I use Aurora RDS with MySQL, so if there is a code issue the connection is not closed properly resulting in unwanted timeouts. And cloudwatch logs also doesn't show any error, so debugging is time consuming. Please advice with a standard way of handling such situations. Thanks.

Comment: Try looking into something like a static analysis tool. Should be able to point out any obvious errors. https://jshint.com/about/

Comment: Unsure if I understood your question correctly but you can implement tests (unit, e2e - depending on your needs), and run these tests before you deploy to production. Ideally these would be triggered for you via continuous integration. Syntactical errors can be caught using linting tools build in to code editors such as VSCode (installed as extensions)

Comment: So for example in below code I had an extra comma after esn. My assumption is this code opens a connection to database fails and never closes the connection. That results the database to timeout in following calls. After I fixed the code by removing the extra comma, I did not see timeouts. Also I don't see any errors for below code in cloudwatch logs. Please feel free to correct me.

`engineMetadata = await EngineMetadata.findOne({
        where: {
          startTime: new Date(event.headers.starttime),
          esn: event.headers.esn,
        }
      });`

Comment: @nopassport1, could you please let me know what extensions can be used in VSCode to catch syntactical errors?

Comment: ESLint is a good one to start off with: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint A quick google search reveals more, depends on your use case/ language etc.

Comment: You guys are saviors. I used ESLint and looked at the errors. I realized how much I missed, wish I had done that early to resolve syntax error. Thank you so much guys TomMillard and nopassport1